# Display Recipes Using App Inventor

Tags: app-inventor

I am using app inventor to build a recipe app. I was wondering how I could take the information from a user submitting stuff into this form [image: Picture] I am very new to app inventor and so I don't think it's complete. I would like to take whatever the user will submit and display it on another screen. How could I do this? Please tell me where I am not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many methods for a user to input data in App Inventor apps. A good example is a spinner.

According to the AI2 documentary, a spinner component that displays a pop-up with a list of elements. It looks like this.

[image: Source: Pevest.com]
*Source: Pevest.com*

The user can select an option. Once an option is selected, a `spinner.AfterSelecting` event triggers.

[image: when Spinner1.AfterSelecting [selection]]

The orange section of the event controller holds a variable. The variable denotes the option the user chose. It updates automatically when a new option is chosen.

You may use the variable provided to send data the rest of the app. For example,

[image]

- The `set` command sets recipeName to the option the user chose.
- If you want to open another screen and send some information to it, use the `startScreen with startValue` function. It allows you to send custom text, which you can get on the other screen using the `Get Start Value` under `Control` blocks